# Multiple master page angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm starting a new project and am going to be using angularjs.
The page structure is the follow:

```
/views
 loginView.html
 mainView.html
loginMaster.html
mainMaster.html
```

My problem is set the other master page(mainMater.html) after the login.

The routing function is follow:

```
 mainapp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        controller : 'loginController',
        templateUrl : '/views/loginView.html'
    }).when('/', {
        controller : 'mainController',
        templateUrl : '/views/mainView.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/login'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is great for **single page** applications, which means if you exit the context of javascript by loading an entirely new page, you'll have to setup the context again. I would recommend you to have just one master page (load the page from the server once and perhaps have something like:)

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-view>
```

and keep changing the entire view within the ng-view context. Have the login screen, signed in experience, all of it in the same place.